# Error while running latex with a tex file created using XSLTML 2.1.2

Tags: xslt, latex, pdflatex, mathml, xelatex

I am creating a PDF with equation in the below way

Mathml.xml **>** XSLTML 2.1.2 **>** pdflatex

that is I am having an xml file with mathml equations and I am creating a tex file out of it using XSLTML 2.1.2 (XSLT file) and which gives an output of a .tex file, the tex file will be used to create a PDF by compiling it as pdflatex *.tex

but while doing that, there is an error comes in

[image]

**My mathml file :**

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="math equation" display="inline" altimg-width="389" altimg-height="57" altimg="../images/altmath_10486.png">
<mtable columnalign="left left">
    <mtr>
        <mtd>
            <mo>⤹</mo>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mo>Σ</mo>
            <msub>
                <mi>M</mi>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>C</mi>
                </mrow>
            </msub>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <mn>0</mn>
            <mo>;</mo>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
            <mo>−</mo>
            <msub>
                <mi>M</mi>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>C</mi>
                </mrow>
            </msub>
            <mo>−</mo>
            <mn mathvariant="normal">540</mn>
            <mspace width="0.33em"/>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">N</mi>
            <mo mathvariant="normal">(</mo>
            <mn mathvariant="normal">2</mn>
            <mspace width="0.33em"/>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">m</mi>
            <mo mathvariant="normal">)</mo>
            <mo mathvariant="normal">=</mo>
            <mn>0</mn>
        </mtd>
    </mtr>
    <mtr>
        <mtd/>
        <mtd>
            <msub>
                <mi>M</mi>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>C</mi>
                </mrow>
            </msub>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <mo>−</mo>
            <mn mathvariant="normal">1080</mn>
            <mspace width="0.33em"/>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">N</mi>
            <mo mathvariant="normal">⋅</mo>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">m</mi>
            <mspace width="35pt"/>
            <mi mathsize="normal" mathcolor="#ef3f3e" mathvariant="sans-serif-italic">Ans.</mi>
        </mtd>
    </mtr>
</mtable>
```

my Tex :

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}⤹+\Sigma {M}_{C}=0;& -{M}_{C}-\mathrm{540}\phantom{\rule{0.33em}{0ex}}\mathrm{N}\mathrm{\left(}\mathrm{2}\phantom{\rule{0.33em}{0ex}}\mathrm{m}\mathrm{\right)}\mathrm{=}0\\ & {M}_{C}=-\mathrm{1080}\phantom{\rule{0.33em}{0ex}}\mathrm{N}\mathrm{\cdot }\mathrm{m}\phantom{\rule{35pt}{0ex}}\textcolor[rgb]{0.9372549019607843,0.24705882352941178,0.24313725490196078}{\mathsf{Ans.}}\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I am new to MathML and Tex, so anyone suggest a solution for this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) also reads MathML (you can just pretend it's an HTML file):

```
pandoc -f html -t latex Mathml.xml
```

If you have LaTeX installed, you can even get a PDF directly:

```
pandoc -f html Mathml.xml -o output.pdf
```

Comment: Hi mb21, thanks for the reply, I have tried this and got the PDF but "⤹" not rendering and also is there any way to adjust font-style and font-size?

Comment: sure, have a look at the [manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), e.g. `pandoc -V fontfamily ...` The arrow not rendering is probably precisely because the font doesn't have the character... maybe also try `--latex-engine xelatex`

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your swift reply, this is really interesting, Ok so I will try with another font, but 1 more question, is there a way to reduce the pdf output page size as equal to its content ?

Comment: I think something like `pandoc -V mainfont=arev -V documentclass=standalone` should do the trick...

Comment: pandoc -V mainfont="Times New Roman" -V documentclass=standalone  -f html Mathml.xml -o output.pdf 

Font-style not working (sorry correct me if wrong) and "standalone" working but equation number is not required in that, any way for that friend ?

Comment: not sure how to do that with html/mathml input... I think you get equation numbers if you have DisplayMath (as opposed to InlineMath) in the pandoc document model, so maybe you'll have to write a [filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to change that... feel free to ask on pandoc-discuss

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support !